# OneHotEncoding a (categorical) column but with the value of another column of the Dataframe (not with value "1")

Tags: python, transform, one-hot-encoding

(my first question on StackOverFlow, so please be indulgent).

I am coding a ANN on a set of data containing among others the following columns:

```
[... , 'labels_column', 'Content %']
```

I would like to have the `labels_column` to be Encoded (like with a OneHotEncoder, which I am using now) to numeric, but would like the values to be the ones from column `'Content %'` and not `1`

For example:

| labels_column | Content % |
| --- | --- |
| label_1 | 37 |
| label_2 | 24 |
| label_3 | 12 |
| label_2 | 60 |

Turned after the Transform into:

| label_1 | label_2 | label_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 37 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 24 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 12 |
| 0 | 60 | 0 |

And not:

| label_1 | label_2 | label_3 | Content % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 37 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 24 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 12 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 60 |

Haven't managed yet doing it with masks, or other tricks...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a math/broadcasting trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels_column': ['label_1','label_2','label_3','label_2'],
                   'Content %': [37, 24, 12, 60]})

pd.get_dummies(df['labels_column']) * df[['Content %']].values
```